# Con qué se debería de hacer login en una GraphQL API, con REST o con GraphQL?

Tags: api, login, rest, backend, graphql

Tengo una GraphQL API, pero tengo duda en si hacer el login en una mutation o hacerlo en un endpoint REST, sé que se puede hacer de ambas formas, pero he leído e incluso en un curso de Fernando Herrera sobre GraphQL, menciona que para el login lo ideal es tener un endpoint REST en lugar de una mutación. Hay alguna best practice para esto?

¿Algún comentario?